# Can Linq.Contains throw "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." exception?

Tags: c#, linq, exception, collections, dictionary

I have following code that adds some values to the dictionary. Can `Linq.Contains` methods throw `System.InvalidOperationException` `"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."` when item will be adding to the dictionary?

```
private static object _lock = new object();
private static Dictionary<Type, A> _dic = new Dictionary<Type, A>();

public static AddNewValue(Type t, A value)
{
    if ( !_dic.Keys.Contains( t ) )
    {
        lock ( _lock )
        {
            if ( !_dic.Keys.Contains( t ) )
            {
                _dic.Add( t, value );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `_dic.ContainsKey`.  I think using `_dic.Keys.Contains` defeats the whole purpose of using a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is not thread safe. If one thread is modifying the dictionary while another thread executes the `Contains` outside the lock, you will get an exception.